# Pyspark converting dataframe to rdd and split

Tags: list, dataframe, split, rdd

I have a dataframe and I did convert it to rdd but when I apply split function I got an error message

Here is my dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, '2013-07-25 00:00:00.0',100,'CLOSED'),
                        (2, '2013-07-25 12:23:00.0',200,'PENDING PAYMENT'),
                        (3, '2013-07-25 03:30:00.0',400,'PENDING PAYMENT'),
                        (4, '2013-07-25 12:23:00.0',50,'COMPLETE'),
                        (5, '2013-07-25 12:23:00.0',50,'CLOSED'),
                        (6, '2013-07-26 02:00:00.0',300,'CLOSED'),
                        (7, '2013-07-26 6:23:00.0',10,'PENDING PAYMENT'),
                        (8, '2013-07-26 03:30:00.0',5,'PENDING PAYMENT'),
                        (9, '2013-07-26 2:23:00.0',20,'COMPLETE'),
                        (10,'2013-07-26 1:23:00.0',30,'CLOSED')],
                        ['Id', 'Date', 'Total', 'Transaction'])
```

I did convert to list and rdd

```
rdd = df.rdd.map(list).collect()
rdd_df=sc.parallelize(rdd)
```

Then apply

```
 rdd_df.map(lambda z: z.split(","))
```

"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'"

But rdd_df is not a list, let's check

```
type(rdd_df)
pyspark.rdd.RDD
```

What might be the problem? I would like to map and add the column 3.Desired output will be like ;

```
  (PENDING PAYMENT,4),(COMPLETE,2),(CLOSED,4)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am sorry I added what the desired output will look like

Comment: Can you try `rdd_df.map(lambda x: x[3])`?